# How to parse JSON data into columns with PL/SQL?

Tags: json, plsql

I have a DB table with 2 columns, and the CLOB column is storing JSON data:

```
NAME VARCHAR2(20),
PHONE_NUMBERS CLOB
```

I have records like the following:

| NAME | PHONE_NUMBERS |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | [{"type":"Office","number":"909-555-7307"}, {"type":"Mobile","number":"415-555-1234"}] |
| MAY | [{"type":"Mobile","number":"206-123-4567"}, {"type":"Home","number":"415-444-5555"}] |

How can I create a DB view with showing data like the following? How should the select statement look like?

| NAME | HOME | MOBILE | OFFICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN |  | 415-555-1234 | 909-555-7307 |
| MAY | 415-444-5555 | 206-123-4567 |  |

Comment: Are you using Oracle? If yes, what version?

Comment: Yes, I am using Oracle DB 19c.